# Grails : Update table in GSP with data from Controller

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy

I have a Grails (2.4.3) application in which there's a table in the GSP page and that table needs to be populated based on a button click. When the button is clicked, it will pass a id to the controller and a search is done based on that number.

GSP:

```
<table id="availUsers">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="sortable"><g:message code = '' default = 'Name'/></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><g:message code = '' default = 'Age'/></th>
                        <th class="sortable"><g:message code = '' default = 'Status'/></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <g:each in="${sortedListUser}" status="i" var="user">
                    <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: user, field: "Name")}</g:link></td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: user, field: "Age")}</td>
                        <td>${fieldValue(bean: user, field: "Status")}</td>
                    </tr>
                </g:each>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#idText").click(function () {                  
                id = document.getElementById("userIdText").value;
                if (id) {
                      d = {
                              userID: id
                          };
                      $.ajax({
                              type: "POST",
                              url: "${createLink(action:'searchUsers', controller:'CustomerSupport')}",
                              data: d,
                              async: false,
                              dataType: 'text',
                              cache: false,
                              success: function(result) {
                                  if(result =='success') {
                                      // To DO
                                  } else {
                                     $(".error").html(result);
                                  }
                              }
                      });
                  }      
            });
```

Controller:

```
@Transactional
def searchUsers (CustomerSupport customerSupportInstance, long userID) {
    String id = params.userID;
    customerSupportInstance.sortedListUser = UserList.findAllByStatus(id);

    if (customerSupportInstance.sortedListUser.size <= 0) {
        render "failed"
    }
    else {
        render "success"
    }       
}
```

As you could see, i haven't got to the point of updating/drawing the table rows.

If you looks at the JavaScript section, inside the

```
if(result =='success') {
                                      // To DO
                                  }
```

This is where i would expect to add some code to update the table rows. The initial view of table is that it will only have headers and no rows.

Someone please tell me how to update/populate the table rows. All the code i posted above is working!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are mixing 2 distinct methods to generate your table rows; you should choose either of this 2 ways:

1) Allow GSP to generate your table
This will require the same page to be reloaded with additional parameters. sortedListUser will be empty on first load (w/o param) but will contain rows information when userID is entered and button clicked (with param). You do not need Javascript for this.

In your GSP, make a form as such:

```
<g:form controller="yourController">
    <g:textField name="userID" value="" />
    <g:actionSubmit value="Submit" action="searchUsers"/>
</g:form>
```

In your controller, do this:

```
render(view: "yourViewName", model: [sortedListUser: UserList.findAllByStatus(params.userID)])
```

2) Render your table rows with results from the ajax call
With this method, the page doesn't refresh. You will need to construct your table rows with Javascript.

In your Javascript, you could do something like this:

```
success: function(result) { 
    var tbody = $('#availUsers tbody');
    $.each(result, function(index, val) {
        var nameTd = $('<td>'+val.name+'</td>');
        tbody.append(nameTd);
        // create and append other tds
    }
}
```

In your controller, create a new method that your ajax will call to and return:

```
render UserList.findAllByStatus(params.userID) as JSON
```

Comment: Hello Jayson, i have an issue with clicking on the dynamically created table rows. I have added a new question for that here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139687/grails-dynamically-populated-table-rows-are-not-selectable-clickable  

Please take a look at that let me know how to do that! 
I appreciate your prompt response!