# Grails : Dynamically populated table rows are not Selectable & Clickable

Tags: jquery, grails

I have a Grails (2.4.3) application in which I dynamically populate table rows with JSON data.

The problem am facing now is,

1. In table rows the click event is not working.
2. CSS styles are not working in table rows when mouse hover happens.

Basically the table rows are dead as far as user input is concerned, but i can update/populate the rows with whatever data i want.

GSP:

```
<table id="availUsers">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#idText").click(function () {
   id = document.getElementById("userIdText").value;
   if (id) {
      d = {
         userID: id
      };
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "${createLink(action:'searchUsers', controller:'CustomerSupport')}",
         data: d,
         async: false,
         dataType: 'JSON',
         cache: false,
         success: function(result) {
            if (result =='success') {
               $(".headerAvailRd").text("Available Users");
               var thead = $('#availUsers thead');
               thead.empty();
               var initialTR = "<tr>";
               thead.append(initialTR);
               var user = $('<th>'+'User'+'</th>');
               thead.append(user);
               var age = $('<th>'+'Age'+'</th>');
               thead.append(age);
               var status = $('<th>'+'Status'+'</th>');
               thead.append(status);
               var finalTR = "</tr>";
               thead.append(finalTR);

               var tbody = $('#availUsers tbody');
               tbody.empty();
               $.each(result, function(index, val) {
                  var initialTR1 = "<tr class='availRdr'>";
                  tbody.append(initialTR1);
                  var user1 = $('<td>'+val.user+'</td>');
                  tbody.append(user1);
                  var age1 = $('<td>'+val.age+'</td>');
                  tbody.append(age1);
                  var status1 = $('<td>'+"val.status"+'</td>');
                  tbody.append(status1);
                  var finalTR1 = "</tr>";
                  tbody.append(finalTR1);
               });
            } else {
               $(".error").html(result);
            }
         }
      });
   }
});
```

All the code above is working.

So the issue am facing is that, the table rows are not clickable & selectable. I want to be able to click on table rows and then get the value of corresponding td.

For e.g., when i click on row 1, i want to get the "user" value so that it could be used to fetch more info from the server and displayed.

Selectable means, there should be a background color for each row and when mouse is hovered above that this background color should change.

Someone please tell me how to make the table rows Selectable & Clickable.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to replicate the default functionality of GSP generated table. You could load a table of data and perform an inspect element to look at how it is constructed.

For 'Selectable', you will probably only need to add the CSS classes onto .

For clicking, you will need to generate a link to the specific user ID. You could choose to hardcode the URL but the right way will be to either from your controller or with a g:createLink tag. For g:createLink tag, you can store the string output from  in a JS variable (on first load, not ajax) and then manipulate the link string, replacing the ID part of it with the row's ID.

Comment: I tried everything you suggested, and it doesn't work.